# Show countdown time same on each machine in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating count down timer in jquery. It is count down the time from 5 minutes. It is working well. But here I need some changes in Countdown timer. I want to show same count down time on each machine whenever user get into the web page.Timer will start after time of interval and it should show countdown on each machine

Here is code

```
var timer2 = "5:01";
var interval = setInterval(function() {


  var timer = timer2.split(':');
  //by parsing integer, I avoid all extra string processing
  var minutes = parseInt(timer[0], 10);
  var seconds = parseInt(timer[1], 10);
  --seconds;
  minutes = (seconds < 0) ? --minutes : minutes;
  if (minutes < 0) clearInterval(interval);
  seconds = (seconds < 0) ? 59 : seconds;
  seconds = (seconds < 10) ? '0' + seconds : seconds;
  //minutes = (minutes < 10) ?  minutes : minutes;
  $('.countdown').html(minutes + ':' + seconds);
  timer2 = minutes + ':' + seconds;
}, 1000);
```

Comment: So you want the time remaining to be the same for all users regardless of when they loaded the page?

You would need to create an actual time reference point and countdown to that. You can use a plugin like this one, the sample on their page counts down to new years. http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/  

If I have misunderstood, please clarify the question :-)

Comment: Yes I need time remaining same for all users. But it will count down time from 5 minutes :) @WilliamCross

Comment: You will need to reference a point of common time. Your current code will just count down 5 minutes from whenever the page loads. You would need to use an internet time reference or use something like the above jQuery module to set a specific date and time it counts down to if you want it to be the same for all users. JavaScript is entirely client-side, meaning it loads on the users machine and thus doesn't have a way of knowing other machines timers. This is why you would have to reference a specific date and time for the countdowns to be accurate. I hope this helps.